# Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type MutableLiveData<User> in Android ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, build-error, parcel, mutablelivedata

I'm getting a compilation build error when I add a MutableLiveData object to my view model in my Android Studio project. I'm not calling getUser() or setUser() anywhere yet and I added the exact same object to a different view model in my project and haven't gotten an error, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Error: 
`error: Parceler: Unable to find read/write generator for type androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<com.example.demometvtest1.User> for com.example.demometvtest1.RegisterViewModel.user`

RegisterViewModel.java:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

@Parcel
public class RegisterViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void setUser(String user) {
        return user;
    }

    public MutableLiveData<User> getUser() {
        this.user.setValue(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to make your ViewModel parcelable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the annotation `@Parcel`: you are trying to [automatic](https://proandroiddev.com/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize-b998d5a5fcac) generate `writeToParcel()` & `createFromParcel()` and the annotation processor doesn't find a read/write implementation for MutabileLiveData (that it's not parcelable). 
Remove the annotation, make the class implement the parcelable interface and make your own implementation of parcelable metods `writeToParcel()` & `createFromParcel()` if you need It or simply remove the annotation.